# How do I set an existing SimpleXMLElement attribute?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am running the following code:

```
$attributes = $xmlTable2->attributes();
foreach ($attributes as $key => $value) {
    $xmlTable1->addAttribute($key, $value);
}
```

But it causes an error:

```
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::addAttribute(): Attribute already exists in ... on line 100
Buildfile: /.../vendor/propel/propel1/generator/build.xml
```

How do I override the value of an existing attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to just use the attributes() function that is part of the SimpleXML object on the element you want to get the attributes for.

```
$xmlTable1->elementYouWantAttrsFor->attributes()->attrName = newAttrValue;
```

or if each $xmlTable1 element is what you want

```
$xmlTable1->attributes()->attrName = newAttrValue;
```

Here is the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php). The comments show how to do this.

Comment: `$xmlTable1[$key] = $value` is easy too.

Comment: I was reading the comments on [this page](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addattribute.php), to which the first comment matched my issue. I'll try this now.

Comment: @salathe Indeed it does. I just like to try and keep things as close to just using the API as much as possible.

Comment: This worked! I also tried @salathe's line, and it worked as well.

Comment: Yup, both do work! Glad to hear it solved your problem!

Comment: Will these also work on adding nonexistent attributes? I changed an old line of code to the first solution and it is no longer adding new attributes.

Comment: Yes, the second solution works on both adding _and_ editing elements. The first solution only works on editing elements.